# State Error C2535 dflt_ctor_closure(void)': member function already defined or declared

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a C++ project and I get this error. I know the error is because I have 2 functions with the same name but they have different arguments. How to fix this?

```
BaseE::BaseE(double x=0.0, double y=0.0)
{
    ......
}

BaseE::BaseE(double x=0.0):
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: With almost 100 reputation and you don't create an MCVE? :/ :/ :/

Comment: Why do you need two functions?

Comment: @gsamaras what do you mean? StoryTeller I call them based on how many arguments I need

Comment: In what circumstance would you *need* to call the second one? Why won't calling the first with `y=0.0` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **default constructor** for a class is a constructor that takes no arguments. It's special: the compiler will generate one if you don't define one (oversimplified). Here, the class has **two** default constructors, because each one of those can be called with no arguments. That's why it's complaining. Too many default arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The way you currently have it, when the compiler encounters a call to BaseE(), it can't tell if you meant to call BaseE(0.0, 0.0) (the first constructor, with default arguments), or BaseE(0.0) (the 2nd constructor with default arguments). This is the ambiguity the compiler is complaining about;
You should remove the default arguments from (at least) one of the constructor implementations.